# Renewal Theory application

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

> Each time a certain machine breaks down it is replaced by a new one of the same type. In the long run, what percentage of time is the machine in use less than one year old, call it $T_{\infty}$, if the life distribution is given by $F$?

The solution is presented as
$$ T_{\infty} = \frac{1}{E[T]}\int_{0}^{1}(1-F(x))\phantom{.}dx $$

My question is, why does the integral include $1 - F(x)$? I do not understand the formulation.

I know that $F_{T}(x) = P(T \leqslant x)$ so then $1 - F_{T}(x) = P(T > x)$ but it doesn't make immediate sense to me why it is set up this way.

Answer (score 2):

The intergral is the expected duration in which any given machine is less than one year old. Dividing by the expected life-time of the machine yields the fraction of time that the machine in use is less than one year old.

Comment: Thank you. But, why not just integrate $\int_{0}^{1}F(x)dx$? Why does the $1 - F(x)$ come in?

Comment: @clocktower: Because $1-F(x)$ is the fraction of machines that are still alive after $x$. $F(x)$ would be the fraction of machines that are dead.

Comment: Ah, I see. That clarifies the situation.

Answer (score 2):

The long run distribution of the age of the machine currently in use has density
$$
g(x) = {1-F_T(x)\over E[T]},\qquad x>0.
$$
The long run probability that the age of the current machine is less than one (year) is therefore $\int_0^1 g(x)\,dx$.